# Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger isn't working when collapsed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

For some reason, the hamburger menu is no longer showing up when scaling my application down. I did not change anything in the code but cannot seem to track down what broke it. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

```
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary bg-dark">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Market Monster</a> <button aria-controls=
"navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class=
"navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type=
"button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggler-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">Guest</a>
    </li> -->
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Market Monster</a> <button aria-controls=
"navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class=
"navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type=
"button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggler-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">Guest</a>
    </li> -->
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- <a class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" href="/signin">Log In</a> -->
</div>
```

Comment: apparently a `</ul>` is missing means commented out and the closing `</nav>` too

Comment: I added the </ul> back in but it still did not fix the issue. I checked and all divs, nav, ul, and li are closed now

Comment: looks like the hamburger menu is there but the icon is missing or the color is matching download the sources to verify or change cdn sources

Answer (score 0):

I have spent full days. At last, I have got a solution. It's work for me very nicely.

```js
// Custom js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Hamburger menu toggle
    $('.top-nav-menu ul li a.nav-link').on('click', function(){
        // check if window is small enough so dropdown is created
        var toggle = $(".navbar-toggler-icon").is(":visible");
        if (toggle) {
          $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="top-nav-menu collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="smoth-scroll nav-link" href="#about-section">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="smoth-scroll nav-link" href="#resume">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="smoth-scroll nav-link" href="#testimonial">Testimonial</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="smoth-scroll nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="smoth-scroll nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li><!-- 
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
      </li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)